# Visual Studio 2010 Test Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

I have a solution with some test projects containing unit tests.
When I run all tests, I would like to execute one project at a time, i.e., all the unit tests of the first project, then all the unit tests of the second project, ecc.
Is it possible with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only execute one project at a time in VS -- the "startup project".

Comment: Yes, but I would like this behaviour when I run all the tests in the solution, not when I select a single project as the "startup project".

Answer (score 0):

What you *can* do is set multiple startup projects. To do so: 
In the **Project** menu, under **Properties**, expand **Common Properties** to select **Startup Project**. From here you can select **Multiple Startup Projects**, after which you will be capable of debugging more than one project at once. 
Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like this behaviour when I use the command "Run all test in the solution", not for debugging purpose.

Comment: Oh I see, I misread the question, my apologies. In the Test Explorer, if you have multiple startup projects as I alluded to, only the tests for your opened project come up?

Comment: I built a solution with two projects and two test projects. I add three tests for each test project. When I run all tests in solution, the order is: one test of the first project, then two tests of the second project, then two tests of the first project and finally one test of the second project.
If I set both test projects as startup as you suggest, the order doesn't change. Moreover, if I press F5 to debug two test projects, with both of them set as startup, I obtain an error: "Cannot start more than one local run".